# Insert a picture of my signature right under my name to the right

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have the following document as follows. [image: this]

I need two adjustments.

1. I need signature in print and signature as a picture on the right hand side of the page (which is on the left as it stands now). However, other parts of the document will use the normal left alignment.
2. I also need the signature in print and the signature as a picture aligned vertically.

Could anyone help me with this, please? Thank you!

```
\documentclass\[english\]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}
\usepackage\[utf8\]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage\[printwatermark\]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Thesis Title}

\date{\today}
\maketitle

The work in this thesis is my own except where otherwise stated.

Signature

\includegraphics\[scale=0.3\]{images}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please get rid of all these `\[` and `\]`. Options are just set in square brackets. What do you mean by "aligned vertically"? Sounds as if you just have to get rid of the blank line then. Your code is not minimal. Please reduce! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{graphics}   %% not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Thesis Title}

\date{\today}
\maketitle

The work in this thesis is my own except where otherwise stated.

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{l}  %% if you want centered alignment use 'c' instead of 'l'
Signature \\[1ex]
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
\end{tabular}

Again some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The advantage of this approach over mine is that the whole signature block will be internally left-aligned (so the left side of the typeset name and the signature will align), while the block will be right-aligned with respect to the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\flushright`. Instead of `scale` you can also just measure the width of the original signature and use that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Thesis Title}
\author{Author McAuthorson}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{signature} % adjust width as necessary or use scale

    \bigskip % optional
    Author McAuthorson
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `[` is a special character that `latex` reads as part of a command. You only use `\[` when you want to type the bracket as a character instead of using it in a command.

PS: I generated the fake signature with the `wesa` font package in a separate `.tex` document and then took a screen shot of the result.