# Use ONLY two Chinese characters

Tags: symbols, characters, classicthesis, thesis

I want to add my Chinese name in my thesis. I follow the sample codes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218039/insert-a-picture-of-my-signature-right-under-my-name-to-the-right).

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Thesis Title}

\date{\today}
\maketitle

The work in this thesis is my own except where otherwise stated.

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{c}
{\bf Real Name} \\[1ex]
{\bf Chinese Name} \\[1ex]
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{signatureimage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first name is English and the second is Chinese. How to add Chinese characters, please? Thank you! Please note this is only the place I intend to add Chinese characters.

Comment: The simplest way is to typeset the Chinese name with XeLaTeX and the `standalone` class, and use the PDF for inclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I do not know how to do it. Could you make an example, please?

Comment: What are the characters you want to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest strategy is to create a PDF file with the Chinese name and including it with `\includegraphics` as you already do for the signature.

I'll use [Donald Knuth's Chinese name](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/faq.html) for the example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
高德纳
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

This uses resources found in TeX Live (probably also on MiKTeX).

[image]

With the same idea you can also use XeLaTeX, if you have a Chinese system font.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kaiti TC}% or any other font supporting Chinese
\begin{document}
高德纳
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That **Kaiti TC** looks super *nice*.