# align text content of tabular cell vertically relative to image in nearby cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm using a slight variation of the solution indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218039/insert-a-picture-of-my-signature-right-under-my-name-to-the-right) to insert a picture of a signature next to the name of the person who signs in a document with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\vspace{5mm}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
Name Surname & \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{image.pdf} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result
[image]

However I would like to align vertically the text of the left column to the top of the image in the right column. I tried all the solution I found here without any success.

Comment: You an add valign=t to the options of includegraphics. To use this, you will also have to add \usepackage[export] {adjustbox} to your preamble.

Comment: that works. thanks!